# How to replace item by dropping another item on it using ng2-dnd library

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop

I am using ng2-dnd library for drag and drop option in angular 6. When I am dropping an item on the existing item, I want the previous item to get replaced with the recently dropped item. Any solution for the above stated issue will be very helpful :) 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the above posted question.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
    fruits.splice(2, 1, "Lemon");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Using javaScript I found a way in-order to replace item. In the code snippet below there is an example which depict replacing item 
here the value '1' will remove item from the array from the index '2' of an array and replace with a new element 'lemon'

```
fruits.splice(2, 1, "Lemon");
```